# Javascript setInterval not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using setInterval to call a function that refreshing webcam images within the html body. This works well in Chrome, however, in Internet Explorer the images are not refreshing. Is this because of a caching issue?

```
<img id='camA' class='webcamStill' src='http://10.0.0.157/jpg/image.jpg' alt='Cam Image' />

window.setInterval(refreshWebcam, 3000);

function refreshWebcam()
{
    $('#camA').attr('src', 'http://10.0.0.157/jpg/image.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. You are setting the source to what it already is, so it's not actually changing, so no need to update as far as the browser is concerned.

To cachebust, just do this:

```
document.getElementById('camA').src =
                           "http://10.0.0.157/jpg/image.jpg?x="+new Date().getTime();
```

I used [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) because reasons.

Comment: I figured this out, just after posting! will honour you with the answer. I concatenated the url string with `"?" + Math.Random()` :)

Comment: I used to use `Math.random()`, but there's always that infinitesimally small chance of getting the same thing twice. Using the current time is guaranteed to never get the same thing twice (assuming you're not reloading several times per second)